# Identification of a plant: Green Leaves with Red Streaks

Tags: identification

[image: Please help me Identify this plant!]

Hi! I'm new to gardening and this is my second plant. The first one (a Sedum Plant) [unfortunately :(] died.
The gardener in me hasn't yet though! Or so it seems! So, I've bought this plant recently. I want to be better at taking care of it and do not want to repeat the sad episode again! I couldn't figure out how to find its name so that I could Google around and know more about the caring specific to the plant.
So, Please help me identify the plant!
Thanks for your time! :)

EDIT: Google Image search showed me a few very similar plants but all without the red streaks.

Comment: Nice caladium. Note that they are not hardy in temperatures below freezing. They can be brought indoors and wintered over if it gets that cold where you are.

Comment: @kevinsky :) Thanks but I don't have to worry about that (or so I assume)! I'm from Bangalore and temperature averages about 15 °C in winters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a caladium. I think the variety may be brandywine. They are also called elephant ear. It grows from a bulb and goes dormant in winter.

Comment: Thank You! One more question! When I was transferring the plant from the bag to the pot, it turned out that the pot couldn't hold all the soil from the bag. When I was trying to free the soil, my unskilled hands kind of messed up and a few roots got cut. Will the roots grow back again, or are those shoots going to die?

Comment: Caladium are not horrifically sensitive to root damage, so you should be OK. http://homeguides.sfgate.com/should-pull-roots-off-caladium-bulbs-before-storing-winter-96453.html